# Retornar una clase con dos propiedades desde un metodo

Tags: c#

Buenas estoy realizando una función que me retorne dos resultados.

he estado realizando pero me sale error me podrian ayudar.

el codigo es el siguiente :

```
public entidadd  calcular()
{
 return new Double[] {2,3};
}

public class entidadd
{
double numero1;
dpuble numero2;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Piero en esa clase, numero1 y numero2 esta como privado.. ponele public adelante...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado, entidad es una clase, e intentas retornar un array de Double, deberia ser asi tu funcion:

```
public entidadd  calcular()
{
    entidadd ret = new entidadd();
    ret.numero1 = 2;
    ret.numero2 = 3; 
    return ret;
}

public class entidadd
{
    public double numero1 { get; set; }
    public double numero2 { get; set; }
}
```

Saludos!

Comment: hice lo que hiciste pero no me llama al nombre de la clases adjunte una imagen en mi pregunta

Comment: Si no se especifica, las propiedades de una clase son por defecto privadas. hay que agregarle public...

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón, ahi edite la respuesta

Comment: @PieroDev como dijo gbianchi, faltaban los modificadores de acceso public, asi como el get; set; saludos!

Comment: el get y set son totalmente innecesarios.. sin ellos funciona bien.. pero ok...

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar tuple, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public Tuple<double, double> GetMultipleValue()
{
    return Tuple.Create(1.0,2.0);
}
```

y para acceder a los valores usas item1 e item2 por ejemplo:

```
var x = GetMultipleValue();
double i1 = x.item1;
```

Comment: Si no se va a reutilizar la clase que hizo como tipo de devolución, la Tupla es una excelente opción.